# How to change TWIML during a Media Streams call in Twilio

Tags: twilio, twilio-programmable-voice

I would like to implement a fully programmatic interaction with twilio: the user calls, my server decides what to say, the user speaks, the server analyses the audio and decides what to answer using text-to-speech.

But I can't find in the documentation how to use media streams and text-to-speech at the same time.

With this code I can receive and send ulaw/8000 encoded audio:

```
@sockets.route('/')
def echo(ws):
    while not ws.closed:
        message = ws.receive()
        if message is None:
            continue

    data = json.loads(message)
    if data['event'] == "media":
        # b64decode media.payload and audioop.ulawtolin() it

    ...
    # make a media object with audio in media.payload and ws.send() it
```

With this I can say something when the user answers the call:

```
@app.route("/voice", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def voice():
    """Respond to incoming phone calls with a 'Hello world' message"""
    resp = VoiceResponse()
    resp.say("hello world!", voice='alice')

    return str(resp)
```

How can I use the two simultaneously, during a long user-server interaction?

**EDIT**: changed the title (see my comment below)

Comment: Progress so far: I can change the twiml during a Media Stream call, but as the first twiml had a "<Start><Stream>...", the new twiml must have the same start->stream verb. But this opens a new websocket connection without closing the previous. I'll now try to close the first, but it seems to me that I'm not using the Twilio API properly. To change the twiml during the websocket connection I do: twilio.rest.Client(account_sid, auth_token).call(callSid).update('... new twiml...')

Comment: typo, it is calls, not call: twilio.rest.Client(account_sid, auth_token).calls(callSid).update('... new twiml...')